Reform + reCaptcha v2 on Cargo
I've implemented a Reform form on Cargo which has been working all fine. However, since the client has been receiving a lot of spam submissions, we decided to include reCaptcha tickbox before submitting the form. However, when one ticks the tickbox, the spinning lasts for around 15 seconds and returns to unticked state.
Does anyone know why it would be happening in this case?
Please see the code below for reference:
<div id="mc_embed_signup"><form action="https://officesandm.us15.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=640bb5eed73e512bd84e2f7a3&amp;id=f2ade7dd28&amp;f_id=00e78ce0f0" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="novalidate"><div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll"><div class="optionalParent"><div class="clear foot">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="https://forms.reform.app/headless/QPMuA5/untitled-form-2/i0p3ty/submissions">
    <div>
        <label for="5db0fb31-8f04-4805-84fc-abf8cb7e67ac"><h2>Could you let us know your name?</h2></label>

<input type="text" id="5db0fb31-8f04-4805-84fc-abf8cb7e67ac" name="answers[5db0fb31-8f04-4805-84fc-abf8cb7e67ac]" placeholder="Jane Smith" required="" class="button2"><br>
<br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="a1042f76-fbf3-46c4-a4eb-f295e9069f5d"><h2>What's the best email for you?</h2></label>

<input type="email" id="a1042f76-fbf3-46c4-a4eb-f295e9069f5d" name="answers[a1042f76-fbf3-46c4-a4eb-f295e9069f5d]" placeholder="jane@example.com" required="" class="button2"><br>
<br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="aa58531d-3b5b-4cb7-ae4c-2624ffe23c7d"><h2>What would you like to talk about?</h2></label>

<input type="text" id="aa58531d-3b5b-4cb7-ae4c-2624ffe23c7d" name="answers[aa58531d-3b5b-4cb7-ae4c-2624ffe23c7d]" required="" class="button3"><br>
<br>
    </div>
   </form>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?onload=recaptchaOnLoad&amp;render=explicit" async="" defer=""></script>
        <form action="?" method="POST">
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcxD2oqAAAAAOUVclMkVb7pSqHuCvNJFnDb1fnA" data-action="LOGIN"><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><div><iframe title="reCAPTCHA" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-hn36exgmtrvz" allow="private-token" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-storage-access-by-user-activation" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LcxD2oqAAAAAOUVclMkVb7pSqHuCvNJFnDb1fnA&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9vZmZpY2VzYW5kbTIuY2FyZ28uc2l0ZTo0NDM.&amp;hl=en&amp;v=lqsTZ5beIbCkK4uGEGv9JmUR&amp;size=normal&amp;sa=LOGIN&amp;cb=hw9j6z2adp8" style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-8" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea></div><iframe style="display: none;"></iframe></div>
          <br>
 
        </form>
    <button class="button1" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

I have tried readding the code and adding "onload=recaptchaOnLoad&render=explicit" to the script. In another thread it was advised to include a g-recaptcha div with a site key number which I added as well.
